# Searching through all location, description and title Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I already got great help here, so thanks for that!
I want to have a search form, that searches on my website.
Right now, when I put something in my search form it only searches in the title of the listings, but I would like that the search form also searches through the location and description of the listing .
Here is what I got

lisitng.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.where("title like ?", "%#{search}%")
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

listings_controller.rb

```
def index
```

@listings = @listings.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?

I am sure its a simple fix but I am unable to find what I need.
I appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: You can add to your where clause by using OR and looking in your other fields. Look up some more information on searching databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "location" and "description" are other fields in the class, try changing the search method to:

```
def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    self.where("title like ? or location like ? or description like ?", query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome it works. why did I have to define query = "%#{search}%" in this instance and not when I'm looking for one field?

Comment: Oh, I just tried to save you a *tiny* bit of typing.  You could also have just done `self.where("title like ? or location like ? or description like ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")` instead of defining that variable.

Comment: Or a bit more idiomatically: `where("title like :query or location like :query or description like :query", query: "%#{search}%")